# Increase ulimit in cygwin

Tags: php, windows, shell, powershell, cygwin

I am having a php loop script, For sudden it gives me error "core dump!", then it stops. people advice me to increase the ulimit, so i just wonder, how to increaste the ulimit?

am getting:

```
   mzapc@mzabox ~/test

   $ ulimit -n
   256

   mzapc@mzabox ~/test
   $ ulimit -Hn
   3200
```

I've tried to do $ ulimit -s 2046, with failed attempt. nothing comes out still same response. any advice?, thank you.

Comment: Error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: which ulimit ? try `ulimit -a`

Comment: I very much doubt that Cygwin implements user limits.  Your problem is probably elsewhere.  (I would also question the wisdom of using Cygwin's PHP rather than a Windows implementation of PHP.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug a php script one way is to run

```
php -e <your-script>
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/php